# jquery - How to return html select option to its original order?

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have two Select lists, between which you can move selected options. When I move options back over to the left list, I would like them to retain their original position in the list order, even if the list is missing some original options.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/6qUyK/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store the original position value. You can use the data attribute for this.

Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/UzaQD/).

Store original position:

```
$(option).data('original-position',i);
```

Retrieve original position:

```
$('#listboxFootballPlayers option').eq($(this).data('original-position')).before($(this));
```

Note that some of your code is unnecessary. For example you can use the append method (or before, or after) to actually move the selected element, so no need to create a new one and destroy the previous one.

Also you have to adjust the code a little to work for the last item in the list. My code is just a hint.

Comment: Your method has its own advantage (works if `value` values do not correspond to the sort order), however it is pretty broken if you consider moving back more than one element. All your indexes will get shifted as soon as you reinsert the first one, and `eq()` will be giving wrong results.

Comment: @liho1eye That's right, but I just wanted to give a hint to the OP. I personally would use better jQuery selectors, avoid creating a clone of the item, and check the spot to put the element back by browsing data values previously set to the n-1 and n+1 elements (where n is the removed item). This way each time you move one or more elements you fill up both the original position value, and also fill the adjacent elements, so when you want to move some of them back you can always have a sorted list, without sorting all the list everytime, which I repute unnecessary and time consuming.

Comment: Either I am confused, or you. I don't see how could you make this work by relying on `eq()`. Fundamentally you need to find one element with smallest "order value" that is greater than one you trying to insert, and insert your option before it. There isn't really any way to do it without going through the entire list, because the element that was originally following the element being reinserted could've been removed as well. That isn't much more efficient than simply reappending all the options in the correct order, but quiet a bit more code.

Comment: Also see my further optimized version, that avoids inserting selected element twice.

Comment: Maybe I hadn't been clear with my last comment. I would ultimately not use the eq() method.. instead I will set up data values to the adjacent elements of the ones being removed, this way on my way back I will search through the list and find the right spot to append the element back, as you also are saying :)
Still not relying on any inline attributes besides the data you create at runtime.

Comment: Then I guess we have different opinions on what is important part of the solution and what isn't. In my mind the way positions for insertion are found is important and the criteria for sort order is a minor implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Enjoy :) http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/6qUyK/7/

Comment: @NinjaBoy I don't typically do that, but this is one of those things that are just easier to change the code than to explain what to do.

Comment: I've give @liho1eye the answer, its the method I'd use and no compensation needed for the last value like Jose's or using internal storage.  Keep in mind when marking answers correct is; there's no pressure to mark the first person to answer as correct.  If you read the FAQ on the site they recommend you give your question a few hours/days for others to answer and let the community upvote/downvote answers for you to best determine which one is best.  Usually hours/days aren't needed just a couple minutes for those active to give there thoughts but that's just my opinion on the matter.

Comment: I agree with everyone here, you should never assign the answer to the first person who answered (except maybe when having identical answers), and liho1eye's approach is straightforward and effective. Anyway I have to say I prefer my approach more, as you don't have to rely on any attribute inside the HTML markup, which will make the code cleaner and the script more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6qUyK/4/

Comment: Oh well... too late.  Fun to see how others solved it.  Just to point out, but I did do some of the code clean up that Jose mentioned